# Error while trying to install Ubuntu on my PC

Tags: boot, usb

I want to install Ubuntu in D:/ partition while I have Windows 10 in the C:/.
I followed all the steps [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and got the USB stick ready, but when I start the PC, press <kbd>F12</kbd> and boots on USB stick it shows this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Un5CWl1.jpg]

Comment: Did you format the USB drive as FAT16? I have seen reports that formatting as FAT32 can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

verify that you've downloaded the good ISO file and correctly(finished download). Check if you have a good usb drive. I hope this helps. Don't forget to download the correct ISO for your system. Either 32bits or 64bits